# Alter scalar function in SQL server 2008 that referring in the computed column of a table

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I have created a `scalar function` in `SQL Server 2008` and the same I am referring in a computed column in few of my tables. Now I want to alter the function without dropping the table. But it throws an error:

> Cannot ALTER 'dbo.GetStatus' because it is being referenced by object
>   'Order'.

Is is possible to alter the function? Or do I drop and create all dependable table first and then alter the function?

Here is my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetStatus]
(
    @FromDate datetime,
    @ToDate datetime
)
RETURNS tinyint
AS
BEGIN

    declare @ret tinyint;
    if(@FromDate<=GETDATE() and (@ToDate>=GETDATE() or @ToDate is null))
        set @ret= 1
    else
        set @ret= 0
    return @ret
END
```

And it is referring in a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveFromDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveToDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Status]  AS ([dbo].[GetStatus]([EffectiveFromDate],[EffectiveToDate]))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. You should first drop all defaults/constraints, then alter your function and the add those constraints back. No need to drop the tables.

But you can work around this by the following trick:

add intermediate function that will call your actual function;
alter computed columns to call intermediate function instead of actual.

Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnActual ( @p INT )
RETURNS INT
AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN @p + 1
    END
GO


CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnIntermediate ( @p INT )
RETURNS INT
AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN dbo.fnActual(@p)
    END
GO


CREATE TABLE TestTable(id INT, fn AS dbo.fnIntermediate(id))
GO
```

Insert some value:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable VALUES  ( 1 )

SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTable --selects 2

--throws exception
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnIntermediate ( @p INT )
RETURNS INT
AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN dbo.fnActual(@p)
    END
GO


--succseeds
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fnActual ( @p INT )
RETURNS INT
AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN @p + 2
    END
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.TestTable --selects 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order]
    DROP COLUMN [Status]
GO
ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[GetStatus] ...
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order]
    ADD [Status]  AS ([dbo].[GetStatus]([EffectiveFromDate],[EffectiveToDate]))
GO
```

or even

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order]
    DROP COLUMN [Status]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Order]
    ADD [Status]  AS CAST(CASE WHEN [EffectiveFromDate] <= GETDATE() AND ([EffectiveToDate] >= GETDATE() OR [EffectiveToDate] IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as tinyint) 
GO
```